# use one RequestBody to differnet xml in post method using java Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest

I was writing restApplication using Java Spring boot. I should write post request in spring. Which accept data is text/xml. However Dto which comes in argument of post method can change name of class for example  one time it might come in following view

```
   <Request1>
<Head>
<head>
    <id/>
    <name/>
    <surname/>
</head>
</Head>
</Request1>
```

in the request of the same url address it might come in other view

```
   <Other1>
<Head>
<head>
   </fio>
</head>
</Head>
</Other1>
```

How I can write one post method for several universal xmls in one time. Is this possible to do in Java spring ??. I saw in pyton it is possible to write just assign to variable some response.data and that's it

```
   @RequestMapping(name = "/a",method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    private ResponseEntity<String> get(@RequestBody String data) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        String temp = "";
        for(int i = 0 ; i < data.length() ;i ++){
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(data.charAt(i))  || Character.isDigit(data.charAt(i)) || data.charAt(i) == '<' || data.charAt(i) == '>' || data.charAt(i) == '/' ){
                    temp += data.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource src = new InputSource();
        src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(temp));

        Document doc = builder.parse(src);
        String temp23 = doc.getDocumentURI();
        System.out.println(temp23);
        String id = doc.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent();
        String name = doc.getElementsByTagName("userName").item(0).getTextContent();
        //String pink = doc.getElementsByTagName("request").item(0).getTextContent();
        System.out.println(id+" "+name+" "+temp23);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(data);
    }
```

For now I get from string

Comment: Check the Jackson parsing

Comment: this different thing

Comment: I want to use one ResponseBody which gives differnt type of xml in Post Request

Comment: You'd better have two different URLs for different classes which will convert XML into different objects. But then you might have a common functionality (maybe using generics) which will process objects of several different types in the same way.

Comment: But I have to use only one URLs  for this post method @Ivan

Comment: You can write your POST method to accept request body as `String` and then parse different XML as you want but manually. But for me that case that you are going to pass objects of two different types means that there should be two different URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 1 day search I figured out that Response should return in string and with help of Document class we could parse new xml from string then we can do what we should to do.Request1 is the first xml data in other request it comes from Other1 xml data it dosn't matter.

```
 @RequestMapping(name = "/a",method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
private ResponseEntity<String> getIt(@RequestBody String path) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder()
            .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(path)));
   if(path.contains("Request1")){
    NodeList tagName = doc.getElementsByTagName("id");
    if(tagName.getLength() > 0){
        System.out.println(tagName.item(0).getTextContent());
    }

   }
   if(path.contains("Other1")){
        NodeList tagName = doc.getElementsByTagName("fio");
        if(tagName.getLength() > 0){
            System.out.println(tagName.item(0).getTextContent());
        }
   }
    return ResponseEntity.ok("SAVED");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Do you want to get the different result when you have different data in the response?
If yes then please handle the view inside your controller which view do you want to show for that response.

I hope this will help you to understand.